# Oracle Bi timeouts while connection to HIVE

Tags: oracle, hive, obiee

I'm trying to create new Datasource in OracleBi Visual Analyzer? but dialog displays Timeout error message.
This is log message from log:

```
 <Feb 18, 2017, 9:38:55,614 PM EET> <Error> <oracle.bi.datasource> <BEA-000000> <Failed to write to output stream
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException null
oracle.bi.datasource.buffer.RingBuffer.dequeue(RingBuffer.java:602)
oracle.bi.datasource.service.adf.protocol.ADFProtocolRespBufferedOutputStream$StreamWriter.run(ADFProtocolRespBufferedOutputStream.java:104)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 
<Feb 18, 2017, 9:38:55,639 PM EET> <Error> <oracle.bi.datasource.trace> <BEA-000000> <TIMEOUT_ERROR Request timed out: Request Headers
X-BI-SERVICE-INSTANCE-KEY=ssi
User-Agent=DSS/v1
Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5
OBIEE_SERVICE_NAME=DatasourceService
OBIEE_BYPASS_ADF_PROTOCOL=true
OBIEE_CONN_POOL_TIMEOUT=300000
OBIPARAM_ImpersonatedUser=weblogic
BISuperUserName=tzmv4us7do8ji2xcenylwhafg3qbkrp5
OBIARG_datasourceName=JDBC
OBIARG_targetConn=JDBC (BIJDBC)
OBIPARAM_DriverClass=oracle.bi.jdbc.AnaJdbcDriver
OBIPARAM_TargetType=Hadoop
OBIPARAM_ConnectionString=jdbc:oraclebi://oracle-VirtualBox:9508/PrimaryCCS=oracle-VirtualBox;PrimaryCCSPort=9508;SSL=false;NQ_SESSION.SERVICEINSTANCEKEY=ssi;
OBIPARAM_UserName=tzmv4us7do8ji2xcenylwhafg3qbkrp5
OBIPARAM_Password=XXXXX
OBIPARAM_ConnectionID='weblogic'.'HiveDS'
OBIEE_METHOD_NAME=getObjectsList
OBIPARAM_SchemaClearCache=true
Host=oracle-VirtualBox:9502
Accept=text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, */*; q=.2
Connection=Keep-Alive
ECID-Context=1.e9d4bbd6-0808-481a-8484-f50ed2c2552c-0000031a;kYhnv0YDJPHBBLPUn3VSdGXIVVNLCKIHVKHM5VML5JGLFINN1ODDs9DEn4DDt2C

Cause - The request did not complete within the allotted time.
Action - Check the log for details and increase the connection pool timeout or fix the root cause.
oracle.bi.datasource.service.adf.server.DatasourceServlet.doGet(DatasourceServlet.java:454)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
> 
<Feb 18, 2017, 9:38:55,642 PM EET> <Error> <oracle.bi.web.datasetsvc> <BEA-000000> <getObjectList failed for 'weblogic'.'HiveDS'>
```

I did telnet to oracle-VirtualBox 9508 and service on that port is responding ( I't Cluster Controller there ) so i'm lost why it's : 
 1) connecting there anyways ( i suppose it's should try to connect to HIVE straight )
 2) failing to do it's stuff

Does anyone has same experience ?

Comment: Do you know how to increase the connection pool timeout? This could be due simply to latency between the client (Visual Analyzer) and the server (weblogic Hive server).

Comment: @cdabel timeout now is something like 3600 seconds, i think 5 minutes should be enough. Or not?

Comment: Do you mean that it is timing out after 3600 seconds? Or that you increased the timeout limit to 3600?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. It is timing out after 3600 seconds.